# Meteor: Create a new collection from one attribute of an existing collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor app, I already have a collection `fullList = new Mongo.Collection('fullList');` that is an array of objects, and each object has several attributes, such as Color, Factor, and Tot.

I want to create a new collection - or at least just a new array - that is, an array of all of the Tot values. The pseudo-code would be something like `newList = fullList.Color`, if that makes sense.

I know how to display one attribute in html using `{{Color}}`, but I can't seem to do anything with it in JavaScript.

In case it's relevant, the reason I want this array is I'd like to use D3.js to represent that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your collection is a set of documents (in Mongo terminology), with each document being a serialised object, rather than actually a single-document collection that stores an array. In that case, you should be able to use the built-in `map` function on your collection cursor. Documentation here:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map

This would look something like (using only the document argument in the callback):

```
fullList = new Mongo.Collection('fullList');
newlist = fullList.find().map(function(document) {
  return document.Tot;
});
```

`map()` will iterate over all the documents in the collection - as no arguments are passed to `find()` - and for each document add an item to an array (assigned to `newList`) that is the value returned by the callback function, in this case `Tot`.

Comment: Makes sense reading your comment, but still doesn't work. When I try to print newlist to the console it is just blank, and newlist[2] returns undefined.

Comment: What does your collection look like? That is, what happens when you output fullList.find().fetch() to the console (assuming it isn't too big)?

Comment: Actually I was already able to get it working yesterday and forgot to return and mark your answer as correct, but thanks anyway for the follow-up! I moved the code you posted to a different web page, the one where fullList is created, and it worked. It should have worked elsewhere too, but at least it works now. Thanks!